# Mongoose find a document from three level nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have collections of Topics, Courses, Levels, Orders and Lessions. Providing each schema below.

```
"Topics":{
  course: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Courses'},
  "topicsName": String,
  "topicsURL": String
} // Note here  Course is just an object not an Object Array.

"Courses":{
  levels: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Levels'
    }]
}

"Levels":{
    orders: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Orders'
    }]
}

"Orders":{
  lessions: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Lessions'
    }]
}
"Lessions":{
    _id: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, // Auto generated Field by Mongoose
   "name": String,
   "description": String
}
```

Now I have one of the Lessions ID. Using the Lessions ID, I need to retrieve the Topic Name and Topic URL.

The below Mongoose codes, I used to fetch the Topic details of the given Lession ID.

```
let topic = {};
const order = await Orders.find({ 'lessions': req.params.id});
if (order.length) {
    const level = await Levels.find({ 'orders': order[0]._id });
    if(level.length) {
        const courses = await Courses.find({ 'levels': level[0]._id });
        if(courses.length) {
            const topics = await Topics.find({ 'course': courses[0]._id });
            if(topics.length) {
                topic._id = topics[0]._id;
                topic.name = topics[0].name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Mongo/Mongoose, How can I fetch the topic schema with running a single query?

Comment: Add lession schema also

Comment: @KunalMukherjee: Added Lession Schema